# Ошибка в коде для переименования файла

Tags: скрипт, файлы, php, загрузка

В этом коде где-то ошибка, файл в директорию загружается, но не переименовывается. И в базу не заносится. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

```
function LoadFoto($foto)
{
    $type      = $foto['type'];
    $uploaddir = "avatars/";
    $name      = md5(microtime()) . "." . substr($type, strlen("image/"));
    if (move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $name)) {
        setFoto($name);
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

function setFoto($name)
{
    $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO obyavleniya (foto) VALUES ('$name')");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример с [php.net](http://php.net), $tmp_name строится немного по другому, может поможет:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: помогло? .